# Should I use cable or wires in conduit for my new panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel, conduit

I'm redoing basically all of my electric and upgrading to 200A.  The plans are in another question ([Is my new electric/subpanel plan correct?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/287644/is-my-new-electric-subpanel-plan-correct)) but the relevant part for this question is:

1. Service Connection point on my roof, needs to run to the meter/main on my outside wall, approximately 20 feet down.  This is run (1).
2. From the meter/main, I need to feed a sub-panel inside the basement, through the wall of the building.  This subpanel is where I'm doing all the distribution.  This is run (2) - probably 4-6 feet of cable all told, going through 4 or 6 90-degree turns.

I was planning on using aluminum SEU/SER (4/0-4/0-4/0) from roof to meter/main (run 1), and SEU/SER (4/0-4/0-4/0-2/0) from meter/main to internal subpanel (run 2).  I've been reading and I'm concerned about the bends I need for run (2), particularly through the wall and into the building.

I'm considering doing conduit and pulling THHN or THWN or XHHW (or something else), but I'm in pretty unfamiliar territory.  What things should I consider before settling on cable vs conduit?  What is likely to be easier for me?  What is more durable?  What is cheaper?  Should I be using aluminum or copper?

Jurisdiction is Ohio, going to NEC 2023 in March.

I appreciate suggestions - thanks.

Comment: I can't answer the rest of it. But definitely **aluminum**. That is the norm for big feeders - the bigger they are, the more normal to be aluminum. Aluminum is normally much cheaper, even though it has to be larger than copper for any given ampacity.

Comment: How fat are the studs or joists you're running through? The IRC/IBC limits on hole size are a major limiting factor on conduit runs within houses

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The sub-panel feeder doesn't have to go through any studs or joists - it goes though a single piece of blocking, but I've placed the meter/main such that it shouldn't be an issue.  For reference, though, the joists are 2x10.

Comment: I'd rate conduit as "always more durable" than cable, but that's rarely an issue in practice with huge feeders. As for the bends on run 2, the trick is to have access for pulling where it makes sense - thus, typically using an LB or a 45 degree pulling elbow that has a removable plate so you are not attempting to pull huge wires through 360° (allowable but offten impractical) and if you have 6 you must have pulling access to reduce that to no more than 360° between access points. Sometimes you can use smaller bends if two of the 90s are making an offset, but that's hard to speculate on.